# javascript - how to control if /else if / else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How to control to which if the else is correlated?

ex:

```
if X = 1 { // A
   if Y > 1 { // B
      gothere();
   }
}
else if X < 1 { // C
    gohere();
}
else { // D
   gonowhere();
}
```

how to make sure C and D will not be related to B???

here´s another example:

```
if xxx {

    ...

FM_log(7,"vList.length = "+vList.length);

if (skippingAvancado) 
   if (vList.length > 1)        
    changeVillage();
else {
   if (skipcounter >= maxSkipCount) {
       FM_log(7,"ROTINA ANTIGA SKIPCOUNTER");
       changeVillage();
   }
}
else {
```

Comment: You don't? That's the whole point of if-else if-else. Just make sure you use {} appropriately.

Comment: Please include the entire block of code. It is clear from the hanging `else {` that some has been left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [dangling else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem; it's ambiguous and the language can choose either construct to bind to. Most (if not all) languages group the else with the nearest if, so it would be

```
if(foo)
    if(bar)
       baz;
    else
       bazz;
```

In practice you should always use braces to make sure there's no ambiguity, as you did in your first example. If you took the braces out of the first example, C and D would be attached to B instead of A; since you included them, the blocks work as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

As long as you place brackets around outer `if` statements, you will guarantee an inner `if` is not correlated to an outer `else`:

```
if (X == 1) { // A
   if (Y > 1) { // B
      gothere();
  }
}
```

In your second example, I would add brackets around the first `if` to guarantee its inner `if` is scoped correctly:

```
if (skippingAvancado) {
   if (vList.length > 1)        
    changeVillage();
}
```

Comment: I think I could have phrased this better - but does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

it's simple logic which else belongs to which if... you control it by using the correct brackets and nesting.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, C and D will not be related to B - they are `else`s of the first `if` (A). This is ensured by the braces. In the second example, the `else` will probably correspond to the *second* `if` (`else` clauses are matched to the nearest possible `if`), so you should add braces around

```
if (vList.length > 1)         
    changeVillage();
```

to ensure the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you haven't fully got control of how `if/else` constructs work, with or without block statements I propose the following:

- Always place the statements inside blocs `{/*...*/}`. This will ensure that multiple statements are grouped together correctly
- Use proper indentation (either manually, via your IDE, or via tools like jsbeautifier.org][1](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/code-guidelines/#asi) /). This will give you a visual cue as to which statements belong together. Each time you write a `{` you increase the indentation, each time you write a `}` you decrease it.

Like this:

```
|   |   |   |
if (foo){ // if1
    if (bar){ //if2
        ...
    } else if (foobar) { //elseif if2
        if (foobarfoo) { //if3
           ...
       } // end if3
    } // end if2
} else { //else if1
    ...
} // end if1
|   |   |   |
```

Failing to properly group you statements will in some browsers lead to incorrect grouping giving you a hell to debug.